# Cookies are missing from request object when i loaded app inside Iframe and hitting webserver URL (Hapi JS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hapi.js

i have an app with Webserver implemented using Hapi JS, and whenever i opened an application with browser's tab i am able to see the cookies are injected in Request header.
but if i load my app inside third application through Iframe. there is missing cookies from the header . can you please some body help here .

Hapi JS code

```
server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
  password: 'longpassword-should-be-32-characters-for-pulse',
  cookie: 'my-app-sid',
  redirectTo: '/',
  ttl: 86400000,
  isSecure: false,
  validateFunc: isAuth
});
```

and my API call where the cookies missing from req header

```
  getBookDetails = () => {
    return {
      auth: {
        strategy: 'session'
      },
      handler: {
        proxy: {
          mapUri: (request, callback) => {
            let url = 'https://mydemoapp.com'
            let tokenHeaders =   {   token: request.auth.credentials.token,
                                                  assetid: request.headers['assetid'],
                                                  asseturl:request.headers['asseturl'],
                                                  deviceid: deviceid,
                                                  appversion: request.headers['appversion'],     
                                                  'user-agent': request.headers['user-agent'],
                                                  'accept-language': request.headers['accept-language']
                                                   };
         
            url = url + '/book/' + request.params.bookId;
            callback(null, url, tokenHeaders);
          },
          onResponse: (err, res, request, reply) => {
            wreck.read(res, { json: true, gzip: true }, (err, payload) => {
              reply(payload);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

i am suspecting that since my app is loaded inside the iframe of third party app. and while requesting the webserver URL mentioned above getBookDetails() it could'nt read the cookies by Iframe from the Parent app (Third party app).

can some one help please

Answer (score 0):

I think the first place should be checked in your browser.
[image]